# Speeding up a grouping sets on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a grouping situation like:

```
select 
coalesce(sector_ind, district_ind, area_ind) as postcode,
....a list of array_agg(..) here....
group by grouping sets ((sector_ind, import_date), (district_ind, import_date), (area_ind, import_date));
```

I have a `query plan` situation like:

```
                                    QUERY PLAN                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=6111398.62..157146473.87 rows=5143123 width=50)
   Group Key: sector_ind, import_date
   Sort Key: area_ind, import_date
     Group Key: area_ind, import_date
   Sort Key: district_ind, import_date
     Group Key: district_ind, import_date
   ->  Sort  (cost=6111398.62..6168661.84 rows=22905288 width=50)
         Sort Key: sector_ind, import_date
         ->  Seq Scan on sales_core  (cost=0.00..962628.88 rows=22905288 width=50)
```

As I am trying to speed up the whole query I have added indexes like:

```
create index sales_area_ind_import_date_idx on sales_core (area_ind asc, import_date asc);
create index sales_area_ind_import_date_idx on sales_core (area_ind, import_date);
create index sales_area_ind_idx on sales_core (area_ind);
```

But nothing seems to change the `query plan`.

Any idea how I can speed up this kind of query?